# Recover contacts and images from stolen phone

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, data-recovery

My samsung note 3 was stolen yesterday, the phone is off. how can I get my pictures from the internal memory of the phone and contact numbers? I was registered with google account

Comment: had the device synced to your google account?

Answer (score 1):

if you had synced the device with your google account then you can find your contacts at [google contacts](http://contacts.google.com) and photos at [google photos](http://photos.google.com).