# How to get contact from stolen Android phone?

Tags: contacts

I already read [Recover contacts and images from stolen phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/179544/recover-contacts-and-images-from-stolen-phone). And that answer did not work for me. I have explained it on the question.

My android phone was stolen. I need to get all contact of my phone. I had enable sync in that phone.

When I visit https://contacts.google.com/, it has only a very few contacts (only if contact has an email ). How can I get all contacts?

Comment: Voting to close cross-post as it now is effectively a double-post after migration.