# How to get contact from stolen Android phone?

Tags: contacts

I already read [Recover contacts and images from stolen phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/179544/recover-contacts-and-images-from-stolen-phone). And that answer did not work for me. I have explained it on the question.

My android phone was stolen. I need to get all contact of my phone. I had enable sync in that phone.

When I visit https://contacts.google.com/, it has only a very few contacts (seems like below 10% and all them has an email too). How can I get all contacts?

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing only few contacts its mean Mobile contacts were not fully sync with Google account.

**Possibilities :**

- if he/she hard reset your phone already , there is no chance for
  recovering   or retrieving contacts.
- if he/she is near any known WiFi network for phone , Phone will get
  connected with WiFi automatically and will get sync if sync is
  enabled in phone.
- Report police and try to get phone back and sync it manually with
  google cloud and make sure all contacts available in cloud.